# confirmation message error [error] Element id=popup_ok not found

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i was testing registration page but error "[error] Element id=popup_ok not found" is appearing instead of confirmation message. confirmation message never come on browser therefore i need to add some manual code in source before requesting command

```
 </thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>/portal/Welcome.do</td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>id=register</td>
<td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>css=#registerForm &gt; ul &gt; li.second &gt; input[name=&quot;email&quot;]       </td>
<td>sama@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>css=#registerForm &gt; ul &gt; li.second &gt; input[name=&quot;password&quot;]          </td>
<td>123456</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>name=repassword</td>
<td>123456</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>select</td>
<td>name=role</td>
<td>label=Subscriber</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>name=terms</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>link=REGISTER</td>
<td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>id=popup_ok</td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
```

Output:
after execution below output is received in logs

```
 [info] Executing: |open | /portal/Welcome.do | |
 [info] Executing: |click | link=REGISTER | |
 [info] Executing: |type | css=#registerForm > ul > li.second > input[name="password"]          | 123456 |
     [info] Executing: |type | name=repassword | 123456 |
    [info] Executing: |click | link=REGISTER | |
     [info] Executing: |click | id=popup_ok | |
    [error] Element id=popup_ok not found
```

Comment: Ask question more detailed. You can use xpath instead of id.

Comment: I would recommend taking a screenshot of the page right before executing the command that clicks on the popup.  Secondly, that does not look like HTML IDs.  If that is copy/pasted html, then doing a selector by ID won't work.  You will have to use XPath or CSS as pradeep has said.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last

```
|click | link=REGISTER | |
```

to

```
|clickAndWait | link=REGISTER | |
```